# how to casts and setonclicklisteners on button programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
    btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0); 
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3); 
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4); 

    btn0.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler); 
    btn1.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler); 
    btn2.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler); 
    btn4.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler);
```

how would I condense the above code? (because I have more buttons than that)

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: What does 'how to casts' mean? If anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add them all to an array:

```
Button[] arr = new Button[5];
arr[0] = btn0;
...
```

and you can loop through the array.

```
for(Button b in arr){
    b.setOnClickListener(mButton_handler);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use an array, but this will work (and it is probably preferable to use) a `ArrayList`.

Comment: i'm newbee in java, can you write the code?

Comment: What do you mean? The code is all there. Just add them to an array, and execute the second portion

Comment: @vendy in case you meant how to add something to an array, reference arr[index number] and assign it to the button. You can see that `btn0` is at index 0 of `arr`

Comment: can i doit programmatically too? coz i had 50 button.

Comment: The array you're going to have to do manually. But adding the `onClickListener` is just that for loop